# How to make jbehave-maven-plugin report failures in maven verify Phase?

Tags: maven, jbehave, maven-failsafe-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin, cargo-maven2-plugin

I am trying to integrate `jbehave-maven-plugin` with `cargo-maven2-plugin`.

`jbehave-maven-plugin` is configured to run during `integration-test` phase

```
<configuration>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
    <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
    <verboseFailures>true</verboseFailures>
    <batch>true</batch>
    ...
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
    <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
    <phase>integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

`cargo-maven2-plugin` is configured to [cargo:start](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) server and deploy web app `war`  in `pre-integration-test` phase and [cargo:stop](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) server in `post-integration-test`

My Intention is to

- Starts server & deploy apps in `pre-integration-test` phase
- Run jBehave tests in `integration-test` phase
- Stop server in `post-integration-test` phase
- Report any test failures in `verify` phase

when I try to run this setup with

```
mvn clean verify
```

it works fine when there are no test failures.

However when there are test failures maven stops in `integration-test` phase and rest of the phases are not executed . this results in failure to stop server.

Is there any way to make this setup work so that reports are generated and failures are reported in `verify` phase

just like [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) does with two distinct goals (`failsafe:integration-test`  & `failsafe:verify` ) ?

Comment: In my opinion you have to change `ignoreFailureInView` to true. Furthermore it sounds like the jbehave-maven-plugin behaves not correctly in the situation where a story etc. has failed. Can you show a log file excerpt?

Comment: If I set ignoreFailureInView to true it wouldn't report failure at all